# Slurm plugin developpement by example

Tags: plugins, slurm

I'm trying to  make my own Slurm plugin that store CPULoad and FreeMem data for each node of jobs but can't find any example how to proceed.
I mean, Slurm doc talks about how to write a plugin but without any example.
I have no idea neither how to structure my c code nor how to use Slurm structres to get scheduler data I need.
I'm wondering whether someone has already written a simple plugin that can be used as starting point.

Thanks.